# WHM/CPanel update on a Linux, Apache server

Tags: cpanel, whm

I currently have a dedicated server running the following:

- Apache/2.2.32
- WHM/CPanel 11.44.3 (build 5)
- MySQL Server version: 5.5.40-cll

Because of a security  with the version of Cpanel I am told by my hosting company that Cpanel requires an update. The issue they have is because the current Cpanel is version 11.44.3 they can not update to the latest version.

Has anyone else had this issue and if so what was the resolution?

The hosting company are telling me that the only way around this issue is to have a completely new server configured with all the latest Apache, WHM/CPanel.

This of course would require all the scripts for our web site been transferred to the new server.

Comment: What is the version of CentOS which you are using?

Comment: @Harijith R  Hi and thanks for replying. The CentOS is CENTOS 6.10 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

You have too old version and to avoid possible issues and downtime, it is recommended to setup and new server with CentOS 7 and latest cPanel and then migrate account one by one. This will allow you to check your websites one by one as you migrate. You should be able to generate full account backup and then you can restore it on a new server.

There is possibility to upgrade the version on your existing server but it is possible that it may cause other issues and you may face lots of issues and downtime.